# How to sort a 1D array based on a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In JavaScript, I have 2 arrays.

One is a 1D array and other is a 2D array

The content of the 1D array is:

```
a[0] = "Germany";
a[1] = "England";
a[2] = "America";
a[3] = "France";
```

2D array content is:

```
a[0][0] = "America";
a[1][0] = "England";
a[2][0] = "France";
a[3][0] = "Germany";
```

How can I make the ordering of the 1D array be same as the 2D array?

That is, I want the final result of the 1D array to be:

```
a[0] = "America";
a[1] = "England";
a[2] = "France";
a[3] = "Germany";
```

Is it possible for me to do such an action?

Comment: Does this need *ordering*, because the two arrays are not the same, or could you simply *flatten* the 2D array to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

How are the two arrays being created? You might be better off with a map... something like:

```
var a = {'America':'0', 'England':'1', 'France':'2', 'Germany':'3'};
```

And then you can access them like:

`a['America']` to get 0, or assign them with `a['England']=4;`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the sorted structure in the other array, why not just copy each element from the 2D array over to the 1D array.

```
a[i] = a[i][0]
//Where i goes from 0 to 3 in this case
```

This would save time & computing resources